# first time using pet bottles and have 8 flat

Tags: bottling, bottles, airtight

Is there a special way of sealing PET bottles?
This is the first time I have used these bottles so I just screwed the cap on by hand until I thought it was tight. I have had 8 flat bottles so far and was wondering if there is a special way or tool to put the cap on.

I would like to keep using PET bottles but need help sealing them, as I don't want 8 flat bottles every brew.

Cheers, Bill

Answer (score 2):

None that I know of, perhaps someone will have more insight on that.

A question: Are you re-using soda bottles? If the caps are in good condition they should work fine...

And a tip: you can still carbonate the flat beers by adding some extra sugar to it, closing and placing in a warmer place (I assume you chilled them). The yeast should still kick back into life to carbonate it. Don't need to waste them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. No they are the proper brown Pet bottles and I used new caps to seal them. I will try and regas the next one I find flat as I didn't think I could regas them. Will let you know how it works out. Cheers Bill